# How do I dynamically embed a winform subform into the tab control of a main winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, tabcontrol, subforms

Is there a way that I can hand a Winforms form object to a main form containing a tab control, and have the main form load this form object into one of the tabs?

An additional wrinkle:  *the form object will be instantiated from a different thread than the main form.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it will work when the Forms are created on different threads, but you would normally do this by setting the Form's TopLevel property to False and then adding it to the tab page control (or any other parent control).

Edit: You also need to set the Visible property to True because Forms are hidden by default.

Also, I just tried this and it does work for something like a button created from another thread. But when I did it with a Form, I got an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Do I add it to the Controls collection of the tab page?

Comment: Yes, or you can set the Parent property of the Form to the tab page control.

Comment: By the way, the better way to go is to use an MDI interface as SwDevMan81 suggests. The MDI interface handles the layout and management of the child Forms as you would expect.

Comment: Yo, I think I worked on a CSE305 project with you at UB (haha completely off topic).  It was the lisp turtle game of tag.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like [Multi Document Interface (MDI) tab page browsing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MDITabBrowsing.aspx)?

Comment: Possibly.  But the design of the main form is already a bit locked in.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just call `Add` from the `Controls` collection on the `TabPage`. You will probably want to set the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties accordingly so that the control fills the whole surface (assuming that is what you want).

I do not think creating the control from another thread is a good route though. I am sure you are quite capable of making this hand off thread-safe as far as using the appropriate synchronization mechanisms and whatever. But, all UI elements have thread-affinity which means that once that UI element is created it belongs to the creating thread. You may not have any issues with simply creating (just a constructor call), but I take the rule of keeping **all** UI element logic on the UI thread quite literally and strictly.

Comment: You can't just add a Form to another Control. It will throw an exception. You must first set its TopLevel property to False.